# Reading files from same folder (c++ program)

Tags: c++, readfile

I have a program that draws the Earth and it uses the following code to read the texture file:

```
Images::RGBImage surfaceImage;
surfaceImage=Images::readImageFile("",Vrui::openFile("/home/rodrtu/Desktop/SolarSystem/land_shallow_topo_2048.png"));`
```

The way I have it set up it only works on my desktop, but I want other people to have access to my program files and pictures, and be able to get the program working on their computer. What should I use instead of using `"/home/rodrtu/Desktop/SolarSystem/land_shallow_topo_2048.png"`

If I add a folder to the same place as my .cpp file, should I make changes to my makefile?
Here is my makefile

```
VRUI_MAKEDIR := /opt/local/Vrui-2.6/share/make
ifdef DEBUG
  VRUI_MAKEDIR := $(VRUI_MAKEDIR)/debug
endif

INSTALLDIR := $(shell pwd)

# Set resource directory: I added this images folder to the same place as my 
# .cpp file, but it still doesn't work
RESOURCEDIR = images

########################################################################
########################################################################

# Include definitions for the system environment and system-provided
# packages
include $(VRUI_MAKEDIR)/SystemDefinitions
include $(VRUI_MAKEDIR)/Packages.System
include $(VRUI_MAKEDIR)/Configuration.Vrui
include $(VRUI_MAKEDIR)/Packages.Vrui

# Set installation directory structure:
BININSTALLDIR = $(INSTALLDIR)/$(EXEDIR)
RESOURCEINSTALLDIR = $(INSTALLDIR)/$(RESOURCEDIR)

########################################################################
########################################################################

PACKAGES = MYVRUI

########################################################################
########################################################################

ALL = $(EXEDIR)/NewPlanet   

.PHONY: all
all: $(ALL)

########################################################################
#'make clean'
########################################################################

.PHONY: extraclean
extraclean:

.PHONY: extrasqueakyclean
extrasqueakyclean:

# Include basic makefile
include $(VRUI_MAKEDIR)/BasicMakefile

########################################################################
########################################################################


$(EXEDIR)/NewPlanet: $(OBJDIR)/NewPlanet.o $(OBJDIR)/drawShape.o
```

Comment: A relative path perhaps? Does `Vrui::openFile(...)` work with relative paths?

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't

Comment: What are you using to build your project?

Comment: ubuntu... is that what you mean?

Comment: @Tiago Rodrigues as in CMake? CodeBlocks? Makefile? EDIT I see you're using a makefile

Comment: I would also REALLY recommend learning CMake for this type of work, it builds your makefiles for you and provides much more options(and directory macros to use) http://www.cmake.org/

Answer (score 0):

You should use relative path like Beta suggested. Put a "data" folder on the same folder than your executable and use : 
`Vrui::openFile("./data/land_shallow_topo_2048.png")`

Comment: It's probably "not working" because your current directoyr isn't what you think it is. Try adding a `getcwd()` call and print the result of that.

Comment: I want it to read from a folder that is in the same place as my .cpp file. If I put the whole path for the file (/home/Desktop...) it works, but it only works on my computer and not on other people's.

Comment: The place of you cpp file may not be the same as your exec file, you should try to get the current directory by using this : http://manpagesfr.free.fr/man/man3/getcwd.3.html

Answer (score 0):

File opening should be relative to the program directory, so you could create a sub directory inside your source dir for pictures. Make sure to let the user know where to place these pictures however,

```
g-dev@g$ mkdir dat
g-dev@g$ mv pic.jpg dat/pic.jpg
```

then in source:

```
::readImageFile("", Vrui::openFile("pic.jpg")
```

adding the directory in CMake:

```
include_directories ("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR/dat}")
```

adding the directory in VS:

[here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/a494abb8-3561-4ebe-9eb0-6f644a679862/)

(make sure you're using provided MSVS macros for your file path `$(ProjectDir)` or `$(SolutionDir)` )

Comment: I'm going to add my makefile code to the question and you let me know what I'm doing wrong. I added what you suggested to RESOURCEDIR = images

Comment: @TiagoRodrigues You need to prepend your path with an `-I` e.g. `RESDIR = -I/home/Pictures` and call this var as so(example): `gcc $(RESDIR) -Wall -blah main.cpp`